# perl, post data via json

Tags: json, perl

I admit that I am new to Perl and working on some advanced concepts.  So, any patience and assistance is appreciated.

My goal is to write a script that gathers data from the user and then posts it to a website, creating a record via `JSON`. I am using `JSON` and `LWP`

For '*event*', there can be multiple hosts to be specified and have records created.  This is where I am struggling, since each entry for an event must be unique, how am I to accomplish this?

I have the list of hostnames stored in an array.  The following code only allows me to pass a single host.  I need to determine how to iterate over the array and pass each host with the same leading keyvalue (hostname =>).

```
my $params = {
    event => {
            owner => $user,
            hashtags => [$category],
            comment => $epic
            hostname => $hosts_modified,
    },
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what structure you're trying to create.  It might be beneficial to show us what you think the structure should look like.  For example, I could create an array of params, each of which has an `event` with a different `hostname`.  Or I could make `hostname` into `hostnames` and have it be a list of hostnames that (saw)|(generated)|(are involved in some nebulous way with) the event.  What are you trying to produce?

Comment: Hello, thank you.  I finally got it figured out. But, it is actaully the latter, I need to create an event that has an array of hostnames associated with it.

Comment: 'hostname' =[@hosts_modified]
                                       }

Answer (score 1):

To put an array into your data structure you need to create a reference to it. You can do this by putting a `\` infront of your array:

```
\@hosts_modified
```

With this change your code will look like:

```
my $params = {
    event => {
            owner => $user,
            hashtags => [$category],
            comment => $epic
            hostname => \@hosts_modified,
    },
};
```